# Detect theme change in background in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-theme

How can I detect when theme(dark or light) is changed in Android? I need to do this in background(when app is not running).
I tried `BroadcastReceiver` with action `Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED` but it does not work in background.
Maybe I can do this with `WorkManager` with `addContentUriTrigger` to `Constraints`(cannot find any uri related to theme)?